# k8s check pod securityContext definition

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, azure, security, kubernetes

I want to check if pod in the cluster running as `privileged pods`, which can indicate that we may have security issue, so I check if
`privileged: true`

However under the
`securityContext:` spec there is additional fields like

- `allowPrivilegeEscalation`
- `RunAsUser`
- `ProcMount`
- `Capabilities`
  etc

Which may be risky (not sure about it) ,

My question is in case the pod is marked as `privileged:false` and the other fields are true like the following example,if this indicate some security issue ? Does this pods can do some operation on **other pods** etc , access external data?

**For example** the following configuration which indicate the the pod is not privileged but `allowPrivilegeEscalation: true`

```
securityContext:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
  privileged: false
```

I want to know which `securityContext` combination of pod config can **control other** `pods/process` in the cluster ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `securityContext` are more related to the container itself and some access to the host machine.

The `allowPrivilegeEscalation` allow a process to gain more permissions than its parent process. This is more related to setuid/setgid flags in binaries, but inside a container there is no much to get worried about.

You can only control other containers in the host machine from inside a container if you have a `hostPath` volume, or something like that, allowing you to reach the `.sock` file as `/run/crio/crio.sock` or the `docker.sock`. Is pretty obvious that, if you are concerned about this, allowing requests to Docker API through the network should be disabled.

Of course, all of these access are ruled by DAC and MAC restrictions. This is why podman **uidmap** is better, because the root inside the container do not have the same root id outside the container.

From Kubernetes point of view, you don't need this kind of privileges, all you need is a `ServiceAccount` and the correct RBAC permissions to control other things inside Kubernetes. A `ServiceAccount` binded to a `cluster-admin` `ClusterRole` can do anything in the API and much more, like adding ssh keys to the hosts.

If you are concerned about pods executing things in Kubernetes or in the host, just force the use of `nonRoot` containers, avoid indiscriminate use of `hostPath` volumes, and control your RBAC.

Openshift uses a very nice restriction by default:

- Ensures that pods cannot run as privileged
- Ensures that pods cannot mount host directory volumes
- Requires that a pod is run as a user in a pre-allocated range of UIDs (openshift feature, random uid)
- Requires that a pod is run with a pre-allocated MCS label (selinux related)

I don't answer exactly what you want, because I shifted the attention to RBAC, but I hope this can give you a nice idea.

Comment: Thanks! 1+ , so If I recall  it correct, I need to check the following, if pod is not 1. `privileged`  2. doesnt configure the `hostPath` 3. and run as `nonRoot` , am I rights ?

Comment: Yes, plus the RBAC. You can also analyze the answer below and try to smash a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly in the scope of `securityContext` (as of [Kubernetes 1.26 API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.26/#securitycontext-v1-core)), here's few things that may be risky:

### Certainly risky

- `capabilities.add` will *add* [Linux capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) (like `CAP_SYS_TIME` to set system time) to a container. The default depends on container runtime (see for example [Docker default set of capabilities](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/oci/caps/defaults.go#L6-L19)) and should be reasonably secure, but `add`ing capabilities like `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` may represent a risk. [Excessive capabilities](https://0xn3va.gitbook.io/cheat-sheets/container/escaping/excessive-capabilities) outlines a few possible escalations.
- `privileged: true` grants all capabilities, so you'll definitely want to check for that (as you already do).
- `allowPrivilegeEscalation: true` is risky as it allow a process to gain more privileges than its parent.
- `procMount` will allow a container mounting node's `/proc` and expose sensible host information.
- `windowsOptions` may be risky. According to [Kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-standards/) it *enables privileged access to the Windows node.* I don't know much about Windows security, but I'd say risky :-)

### Maybe risky (though usually intended to restrict permissions)

- `runAsGroup` and `runAsUser` may be risky when set to `root` / `0`. Given that by default container runtime will probably run container as `root` already it's mostly used to *restrict* container's permissions to a non-`root` user. But if your container runtime is configured to run container as non-`root` by default, it might be used to bypass that and run a container with `root`.
- `seLinuxOptions` may be used to provide an insecure SELinux context, but is usually intended to define a more secure context.
- `seccompProfile` defines system calls a container is allowed to make. It may be used to get access to sensitive system calls, though it's usually intended to restrict them.

### (probably) Not risky

- `readOnlyRootFilesystem` (default `false`) will make container root system read-only.
- `runAsNonRoot` (default `false`) will prevent a container from running as `root`
- `capabilities.drop` will *drop* [Linux capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), restricting further what a container can do.

You can read more on [Configure a Security Context official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-capabilities-for-a-container)

### What about non-Security Context related risks?

Security Context is not the only thing you should be wary about: you should also consider volume mounts to unsecure locations, RBAC, network, Secrets, etc. A good overview is provided by [Security Checklist](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/security-checklist/).